# How to use kotlin.system with Kotlin Native?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-native

I'd like to use system functions like getTimeMillis() which should be a part of kotlin.system: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.system/index.html

But the compiler says such module cannot be imported. The gradle configuration is like this (kotlin multiplatform project):

```
    commonMain.dependencies {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.10"
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:0.10.0"
        implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client:1.0.0"
        implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:1.1.0"
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:1.1.0"
    }
```

Also I cannot find any example of usage or this module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getTimeMillis()` is only available for `JVM` and `Native` not for `Common` and `JS`.

If you but the call to `getTimeMillis()` in the source directory of the Native module the compiler can find the function.

If you need the call to be in `Common` you have to implement a `Common` wrapper function on your own and implement the wrapper on each platform yourself.

In order to do this create a stub function and a function which uses it in your common module . For example:

```
expect fun getSystemTimeInMillis(): Long

fun printSystemTimeMillis() {
    println("System time in millis: ${getSystemTimeInMillis()}")
}
```

Then implement that function your platform specific modules. For example in a JVM module like:

```
actual fun getSystemTimeInMillis() = System.currentTimeMillis()
```

Or in a native module like:

```
actual fun getSystemTimeInMillis() = getTimeMillis()
```

See also: https://github.com/eggeral/kotlin-native-system-package

Comment: I'm using getTimeMillis() in the native code and it still cannot find the method. :/

Comment: I shared the example I am using on https://github.com/eggeral/kotlin-native-system-package

Comment: Thanks for putting so much effort helping me. I see you project is defined for MacOS, I'm trying to use Android & iOS, with sourceSets enabled - maybe this is the difference.

Comment: In other words, I realize I need it it Common. I just thought "Common" is "Native".

Comment: In this case you need to use 'actual' and 'expect'. I updated my answer and the Github project to show how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone gets here that is using kotlin native (as the title says) the solution is to add an import:

```
import kotlin.system.getTimeMillis;
```

Thanks,